# How to allow downloading a file of 1GB

Tags: php

I want to allow the user to download a file up to 1GB in size, but according to my code only a file of 113MB can be downloaded...

```
header('Content-type: application/zip');

//open/save dialog box
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="check.zip"');

//read from server and write to buffer
readfile('check.zip');
```

Can anyone tell me how to download a larger file?

Comment: Where is it telling you that it can only be 113MB?

Comment: check this. it will help you http://blog.mayflower.de/archives/136-Make-the-download-of-large-files-with-PHP-and-lighty-very-easy.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess from what you've said that you're getting an "out of memory" error.

In that case, perhaps this note from the [documentation](http://php.net/readfile) might be of interest:

> **Note:**
>
> **readfile()** will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own. If you encounter an out of memory error ensure that output buffering is off with [ob_get_level()](http://php.net/ob_get_level%28%29).

So, check `ob_get_level()` and call `ob_end_flush()` if necessary to stop output buffering.

---

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
$f = fopen("check.zip","rb");
while(!feof($f)) {
    echo fgets($f);
    flush();
}
```

---

Another option is this:

```
header("Location: check.zip");
```

This will redirect the browser to the `check.zip` file. Since it's a download, the existing page won't be affected. You can even output the rest of a page to say something like "Your download will begin momentarily" to the user.

Comment: my main problem is that Suppose the server is my own computer and i am testing my website on wampserver...
i placed my downloaded document in www directory in wamp server...
When i download that document from the browser eg zip file of 130 mb. the document downloaded successfully but when i want to open that document with winrar it shows an error "the file format is damaged or not supported" and the downloaded document is of just 38 bytes but its actual size is 130 mb

Answer (score 0):

Either read and echo the file a chunk at a time, or use something like mod_sendfile to make it Not Your Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your file write buffer chunk size to maximum of file. That will decrease the utilization of resources and your download works fine.

Edit:

Use HTML5 webworkers to download large. Webworkers works in background so you can able to download large files.